# Convergence of a series and $ b_k:=\inf\{n\cdot a_n:n\geq k\} $

Tags: real-analysis

> Let be $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ with $ a_n>0 $ for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ . Define $ b_k:=\inf\{n\cdot a_n:n\geq k\} $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $.
> Proof or disproof:
>
> 1. If $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k $ converges then $ b_k=0 $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $.
> 2. If $ b_k=0 $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $ then $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k $ converges.

My idea:

1. Is true.

> With $ a_n>0 $ for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ it applies for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $ that
> $$ b_k=\inf\{n\cdot a_n:n\geq k\} \geq \inf\{a_n:n\geq k\}=0. $$
> Suppose there is an Index $ l\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ b_l>0 $. Then it applies for all $ n\geq l $
> $$ n\cdot a_n\geq b_l>0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad a_n\geq \frac{b_l}{n}>0. $$
> Then it is $$ \sum\limits_{k=l}^\infty a_k\geq \sum\limits_{k=l}^\infty \frac{b_l}{k} $$
> but $ \sum\limits_{k=l}^\infty \frac{b_l}{k} $ diverges such that $ \sum\limits_{k=l}^\infty a_k $ diverges too which is a contradiction that $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k $ converges.
> So it applies $ b_k=0 $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $.

2. Is wrong.

> Chose the sequence
> $$ a_n:=\begin{cases}0,\text{ n is even}\\\frac{1}{n},\text{ n is uneven}\end{cases} $$
> Then it applies for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ that
> $$ n\cdot a_n=\begin{cases}0,\text{ n is even}\\1,\text{ n is uneven}\end{cases} $$
> and $ b_k=\inf\{n\cdot a_n:n\geq k\}=\{0,1,0,1,...\}=0 $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $.
> Now consider the partial sum sequence
> $$ s_{2m}:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m} a_k=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2k-1}\geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2k} $$
> The series $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2k} $ diverges such that $ (s_{2m})_{m\in \mathbb{N}} $ diverges and $ (s_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ diverges. So $  \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k $ diverges.

Is that right?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I think it is right.